# Sliding Window and Recognizing Specific Characters in a List

Tags: python-3.x

Instructions: Write a script that will calculate the %GC of a dna string
based on a sliding window of adjustable size. So say the length of
the window is L = 10 bases, then you will move the window along
the dna strand from position 0 to the end (careful, not too far...)
and 'extract' the bases into a substring and analyze GC content.
Put the numbers in a list. The dna string may be very large so you
will want to read the string in from an infile, and print the results
to a comma-delimited outfile that can be ported into Excel to plot.

For the final data analysis, use a window of L = 100 and analyze the two genomes in files:
Bacillus_amyloliquefaciens_genome.txt
Deinococcus_radiodurans_R1_chromosome_1.txt

But first, to get your script functioning, use the following trainer data set.Let window L=4. Example input and output follow:

INPUT:
AACGGTT

OUTPUT:

```
0,0.50
1,0.75
2,0.75
3,0.50
```

My code:

```
dna = ['AACGGTT']
def slidingWindow(dna,winSize,step):
    """Returns a generator that will iterate through
    the defined chunks of input sequence.  Input sequence
    must be iterable."""

    # Verify the inputs
    #try: it = iter(dna)
   # except TypeError:
    #raise Exception("**ERROR** sequence must be iterable.")
    if not ((type(winSize) == type(0)) and (type(step) == type(0))):
        raise Exception("**ERROR** type(winSize) and type(step) must be int.")
    if step > winSize:
        raise Exception("**ERROR** step must not be larger than winSize.")
    if winSize > len(dna):
        raise Exception("**ERROR** winSize must not be larger than sequence length.")

    # Pre-compute number of chunks to emit
    numOfwins = ((len(dna)-winSize)/step)+1

    # Do the work
    for i in range(0,numOfwins*step,step):
        yield dna[i:i+winSize]
        chunks = slidingWindow(dna,len(dna),step)
        for y in chunks:
            total = 1 
            search = dna[y]
            percentage = (total/len(dna))
            if search == "C":
                        total = total+1
                        print ("#", y,percentage)
            elif search == "G":
                        total = total+1
                        print ("#", y,percentage)
            else:
                    print ("#", y, "0.0")

"""
MAIN
calling the functions from here
"""

#    YOUR WORK HERE
#print ("#", z,percentage)
```

Comment: What programming language do you (want to) use? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm using Python vis Spyder. I'm stuck with the sliding window. I've tried various things I've found online when searching sliding window but it's just not working.

Comment: Here's the rest of what my teacher instructed us to do. He included an example to help us get a better idea.#For the final data analysis, use a window of L = 100
#and analyze the two genomes in files:
#Bacillus_amyloliquefaciens_genome.txt
#Deinococcus_radiodurans_R1_chromosome_1.txt
  
#But first, to get your script functioning, use the following trainer data set 
#Example input and output follow:

#INPUT
#AACGGTT

#OUTPUT
#0,0.50
#1,0.75
#2,0.75
#3,0.50

Comment: Its okay to ask about school work, but it's expected that the poster make a good faith effort and explain what they've tried and why it doesn't work. [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I swear to you I've worked on it for hours and hours, I'm just having trouble posting the code to show where I got stuck because the code is too long. But basically I'm having trouble inserting my code that recognizes C or G and prints out the percentage (only functioning part of my code) into a sliding window argument. I'd appreciate any references of examples of sliding window arguments when searching for letters in a string. I've searched online and tried multiple that just aren't working for me. Also my teacher set the window  L=4 in my most recent comment. Somehow that line was deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the question format suggestions. I believe the issue lies with where I've input my working code into the sliding window function.

Answer (score 1):

When approaching a complex problem, it is helpful to divide it into simpler sub-problems. Here, you have at least two separate concepts: a window of bases, and statistics on such a window. Why don't you tackle them one at a time?

Here is a simple generator that produces chunks of the desired size:

```
def get_chunks(dna, window_size=4, stride=1):
    for i in range(0, len(dna) - window_size + 1, stride):
        chunk = dna[i:i + window_size]
        assert len(chunk) == window_size
        yield chunk


for chunk in get_chunks('AACGGTT'):
    print(chunk)
```

It displays this output:

```
AACG
ACGG
CGGT
GGTT
```

Now, with that in hand, could you write a simple function that accepts a four-character string and produces an appropriate statistical summary of it? [Please post it as a separate answer to your question. Yes, it might sound odd at first, but StackOverflow *does* encourage you to post answers to your questions, so you can share what you have learned.]